# How can I invalidate all of a single users sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Using devise, a user logs in on a public computer, and they forget to logout.

Later, we want to make sure that session is invalidated so that browser is redirected to the login page.

How can I achieve that?

I know I could invalidate *all* the sessions for all users, but how could I do it for a single user (so it doesn't impact all users).

I read something about a password salt changes if you change the password, could that be applied to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what works for me.

I give each user a session_validity_token, and store it in their session data when they login. And it is checked each time they access the server. To force all sessions on all browsers to have to re-login, I simply clear the token.

```
$ rails g migration add_session_validity_token_to_users session_validity_token
$ rake db:migrate
```

> config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user except: :fetch do |user, warden, opts|
  user.update_attribute(:session_validity_token, Devise.friendly_token) if user.session_validity_token.nil?
  warden.raw_session["validity_token"] = user.session_validity_token
end

Warden::Manager.after_fetch do |user, warden, opts|
  unless user.session_validity_token == warden.raw_session["validity_token"]
    warden.logout
  end
end
```

> app/models/user.rb

```
def force_logout
  update_attribute(:session_validity_token, nil)
end
```

Comment: How do you 'clear' the token? Just setting it to an empty string?

Comment: @peterept Hi Pete, have you had any drawbacks with this approach since then? I liked the simplicity of your solution.

Comment: For reference: there is a simplified version of this solution at https://web.archive.org/web/20221002052940/https://makandracards.com/makandra/53562-devise-invalidating-all-sessions-for-a-user

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for you can achieve the following

1. In devise you can set the session time out ,which will make sure that the session will get time out and user will have to login again but this will affect every user ie all the user session will get timed out after a fixed interval of time .

Eg

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 15.minutes
```

2. The second way of achieving this creating a white list of ips from which user will login ,if the user login from an ip which is not whitelisted by user then ,you can implement the session logic there .

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those work for me, because I want the user to be certain that their sessions (from unknown computers) are immeadiately invalidated. I think I have found the solution, by adding a token to the user account and storing it in the warden raw_session hash. Trying it now..

Comment: thanks. I have posted the solution. works. phew. Your answer may help other people though so definitely worth keeping.